# Eject Expo project from virtual machine

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using expo for my react native project, and till now i'm using my actual machine to run and lunch the localhost, everything is working fine. 
So now i made a virtual machine where i installed expo again and copied my project in there,in order to eject my project only on the virtual machine , and keep it non ejected on the real machine.
the problem is when i run "expo start" on my virtual machine i got this:
[image]
as you can see its written"logged in as ..", so i'm afraid if i made some changes on my vm it will affect also the real project and can't inject it back.
 is there a way to avoid this? and what could you advice me to do?
I'm new to react native.thanks for you answers

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do on your VM stays on your VM and doesn't affect your code outside of it. You should store your code in a git repo if you ever fear irreversible damage.

Ejected expo project becomes regular react-native-cli project, you can no longer work with it using expo and need to launch it using "npm start" or "yarn start" command in your project directory. You'll also need some additional installation different for iOS and Android, check out the [official setup guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup).

Comment: hello man i appreciate your response, i do have a git repo for my project, and i've seen the changes that occures when the expo project is ejected, my only fear is because when i launch the localhost on my vm its logged as my expo iD, so i'm afraid it affects my project globaly, but yeah thank you